# How to request more than 20 results from Yelp API?

Tags: python, api, yelp

I am trying to get a complete list of restaurants in Toronto from Yelp. Here is my Python code:

```
import urllib2
import rauth

params="term=restaurants&location=Toronto&limit=20&cc=CA"
consumer_key = "***"
consumer_secret = "***"
token = "***"
token_secret = "***"
session = rauth.OAuth1Session(
consumer_key = consumer_key
,consumer_secret = consumer_secret
,access_token = token
,access_token_secret = token_secret)

request = session.get("http://api.yelp.com/v2/search",params=params)


data = request.json()
```

The problem is that Yelp can only return 20 results. Is there a way to retrieve more than 20 results?

Answer (score 4):

You can increase the limit to 50 by adding the parameter `'limit': 50`. Additionally, you can use the `offset` parameter to iterate over the records. You can get up to 1000 records in total. This is how it could look like:

```
def get_businesses(location, term, api_key):
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % api_key}
    url = 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search'

    data = []
    for offset in range(0, 1000, 50):
        params = {
            'limit': 50, 
            'location': location.replace(' ', '+'),
            'term': term.replace(' ', '+'),
            'offset': offset
        }

        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data += response.json()['businesses']
        elif response.status_code == 400:
            print('400 Bad Request')
            break

    return data
```

Comment: How would I convert this to python 3's urllib? I adjusted `requests.get` to `request.Request`, but then I receive the `AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'json'`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set sort to 0, it returns up to 1000. Otherwise you should use `offest` parameter to get data 20 by 20

Answer (score 0):

Yelp's API returns only 20 results at maximum. You're not doing anything wrong, they just limit it to 20.

Obtaining more than 20 results with Google Places API

However, it seems there is a way to get up to 60 results.